# Analytic continuation of Dixon's identity

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables, special-functions

Many well-known combinatorial identities has an analytic version. For example, the following identities
$$
2^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 
$$
$$
\binom{2n}{n} = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}^2
$$
can be generalized to
$$
2^z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{z}{n}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\Gamma(1+2z)}{\Gamma(1+z)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{z}{n}^2
$$
where $z$ is in a small neighborhood of zero in $\mathbb C$ and $\binom{z}{n}=\frac{z(z-1)\dots (z-n+1)}{n!}$. For the Dixon's identity,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{2n}{k}^3 = (-1)^n \frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3},
$$
it is less obvious to guess the analytic version of it. After some trial and error, I found
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \binom{z}{n}^3 = \cos \left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right) \frac{\Gamma(1+3z/2)}{\Gamma(1+z/2)^3}
$$
To prove this, my idea is to find a functional equation satisfied by both sides of the formula. However, before delving into it, I want to ask if this formula exists somewhere in the literature and in which context.

Comment: There is a very rich theory of generalized ${}_pF_q$ hypergeometric series and identities they satisfy. In the terminating case (the parameters are such that the series is a finite sum) you get the combinatorial binomial sum identities. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_identity and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Identities

Comment: Also, you can find a very elementary proof of the finite sum Dixon identity in my article https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11147

Comment: The identity you found is a special case of Dixon’s Well-Poised Sum (DLMF 16.4.4), where $a=b=c=-z$; see https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.4#E4